# Срабатывание кода по таймеру

Tags: java, android, android-studio

подскажите пожалуйста, нужно сделать чтобы часть кода срабатывала в определенное время, например с 12 дня до 6 вечера, а с 6 вечера до 12 ночи работала другая часть кода, как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать либо, как уже написали, с помощью шедулеров, либо следующим образом:

```
// При необходимости измените "GMT+3" на свою временную зону
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3")); 
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hours  >= 12 && hours < 18) {
   // первая часть кода
} else if (hours  >= 18 && hours <= 23) {
   // другая часть кода
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если приложение установит человек из другой тайм зоны? Как оно у него будет работать?

Comment: @DenisZharikov, насколько я знаю, автоматически средствами языка это сделать невозможно. Однако можно попросить пользователя ввести локацию, и на основе этого определять временную зону (или же попросить его определить сразу часовой пояс). Можете также поискать решение тут: https://habr.com/post/274811/

Answer (score 1):

Для решения этой задачи вам нуден  JobScheduler или же AlarmManager вот офф документация с примерами 
[Офф. документация](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)